# Remove unpredictable date format at the end of string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am getting the strings in the following manner, with date in random pattern at the end. But it will only contain underscore , slashes ,numbers or hyphens.

```
TRAVEL_DELAY_01072015
TRAVEL_DELAY_01_07_2015
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015/01/04
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015-01-04
```

I need to just take out TRAVEL_DELAY from the above strings . I am using regex for this , but isnt working :

```
m = re.match("^(.*)[_0-9\/.]+", abovestring)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the dates just split:

```
s="""TRAVEL_DELAY_01072015
TRAVEL_DELAY_01_07_2015
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015/01/04
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015-01-04"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    date = line.split("_",2)[-1]

01072015
01_07_2015
2015/01/04
2015-01-04
```

Or `str.replace`, there is no need for a regex:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    date = line.replace("TRAVEL_DELAY_","")
    print(date)

 01072015
 01_07_2015
 2015/01/04
 2015-01-04
```

If you were actually trying to parse the dates you could use `dateutil` and fix the strings:

```
from dateutil import parser
for line in s.splitlines():
    date = line.replace("TRAVEL_DELAY_","")
    if any(ch in date for ch in ("/","-","_")):
        print(parser.parse(date.replace("_","-")))
    else:
        date = "{}-{}-{}".format(date[:2],date[2:4],date[4:])
        print(parser.parse(date))


2015-01-07 00:00:00
2015-01-07 00:00:00
2015-01-04 00:00:00
2015-01-04 00:00:00
```

If the digits are only in the date and you want actually want the string not the date:

```
 s="""TRAVEL_DELAY_01072015
TRAVEL_DELAY_01_07_2015
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015/01/04
Travel_Delay_Data_2015/01/04
TRAVEL_DELAY_2015-01-04"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    ind = next(ind for ind, ele in enumerate(line) if ele.isdigit())
    s = line[:ind-1]
    print(s)

TRAVEL_DELAY
TRAVEL_DELAY
TRAVEL_DELAY
Travel_Delay_Data
TRAVEL_DELAY
```

Comment: All of these are great as well. +1 for being like a coding Google.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer .,The string is not always 'TRAVEL_DELAY', it can be any string with any format of date . So i just need to extract the string part . Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @IshuGupta, are there always  two  ` _` in the starting string?

Comment: @padraic No the string can be as follows : Travel_Delay_Data

Comment: can starting string contain digits?

Comment: No @padraic.. the digits will always be at the end after the underscore

Comment: @IshuGupta, you are actually trying to get the string not the date?

Comment: Yes...I just want the string part before the last underscore that is followed by date..

Comment: @IshuGupta, have a look at the last part of the answer and see if we are on the same page

Comment: @IshuGupta, no worries

Answer (score 3):

If that's all you have to do, why not just *remove* `TRAVEL_DELAY` instead of matching the rest? You could implement something like this :

```
m = re.sub('TRAVEL_DELAY', '', m)
```

If your problem is more complex than this, please do let me know.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, you want to remove all alpha characters, so you're looking for this regex.

```
m = re.sub('[_A-Z_a-z_]','', m)
```

Comment: A deleted answer used `m = line[len('TRAVEL_DELAY':]` to archieve that. Can you explain if/why your approach is better?

Comment: No real difference, unless of course `TRAVEL_DELAY` wasn't at the start of the string for some reason, then my method would remove it properly instead of cutting off the start of the string.

Comment: The string is not always 'TRAVEL_DELAY', it can be any string with any format of date . So i just need to extract the string part .

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer .,The string is not always 'TRAVEL_DELAY', it can be any string with any format of date . So i just need to extract the string part . Apologies for the confusion